# Compare Two Strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare Two Strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313485/compare-two-strings-in-mysql)

My current query (doesn't work)

```
SELECT url
FROM table
WHERE
    'http://www.longurl.com/some/string' like '%' . url . '%'
```

table

```
url
longurl.com
```

I am trying to match the record in "table" for longurl.com to any compared URL that contains longurl.com.

Should match compared URLs such as:

```
http://www.longurl.com/some/string
http://longurl.com
http://longurl.com/some/string
```

In this PHP example, it is very easy to compare:

```
$url = "http://www.longurl.com/some/string";    
if(strstr($url, 'longurl.com')) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure";
}
```