# Compare Two Strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My current query (doesn't work)

```
SELECT url
FROM table
WHERE
    'http://www.longurl.com/some/string' like '%' . url . '%'
```

table

```
url
longurl.com
```

I am trying to match the record in "table" for longurl.com to any compared URL that contains longurl.com.

Should match compared URLs such as:

```
http://www.longurl.com/some/string
http://longurl.com
http://longurl.com/some/string
```

In this PHP example, it is very easy to compare:

```
$url = "http://www.longurl.com/some/string";    
if(strstr($url, 'longurl.com')) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LIKE` (uppercase)?

Comment: can you do it without the http ?   %//longurl.com/%   Its possible the : is confusing the parser.

Comment: have you tried '%longurl.com/%'

Comment: sql is not case sensitive ...  just easier to read for some people so they code that way ... I personally don't capitalize anything

Comment: No, like '%http://longurl.com%' does not return a match

Comment: Do you already know the value for the longurl?

Comment: No, the value for longurl.com comes from the database.. what's being dynamically added to the query is the "hxxp://www.longurl.com/some/string" part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, what about:

```
SELECT url 
  FROM table 
 WHERE INSTR('http://www.longurl.com/some/string', url) > 0
```

(Formatting didn't work so well in the comments, so I added it again as an answer.)

Comment: This is the weapon of choice for find column value somewhere in a constant. It's also easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is getting all URLs containing `longurl.com` then try using:

```
SELECT url
FROM table
WHERE
url like '%longurl.com%'
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
LIKE '%longurl.com%'
```

Comment: this answer is not going to work because the comparator for url must be exactly like the examples I've provided for matches.. it's dynamic from a PHP variable

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or escaping some of the characters in your URL string.  OR omitting the http: part .. I believe the `:` could be confusing the parser ...

```
so try   %//longurl.com/%
```

or even

```
%longurl.com%  if possible
```

or even

```
http://longurl.com/%
```

Comment: This does not work.. matching longurl.com to %longurl.com/some/page% is not a match. LIKE() is not the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
SELECT url
FROM table
WHERE
    url like '%http://%longurl.com%'
```

or you can also use %longurl.com%

Comment: are you using a case insensitive collation?

Comment: this answer is not going to work because the comparator for url must be exactly like the examples I've provided for matches.. it's dynamic from a PHP variable

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation operator `.` does not exist in MySQL, you have to use the [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function instead:

```
SELECT url
FROM table
WHERE 'http://www.longurl.com/some/string' LIKE CONCAT('%', url, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT url 
FROM table
WHERE url LIKE '%longurl.com%string%'
```

or, to be just like your PHP:

```
SELECT url 
FROM table
WHERE url LIKE '%longurl.com%'
```

Comment: that's not going to work because longurl.com is not the dynamically inserted text, the "hxxp://www.longurl.com/some/string" part is